# Why does IIS deny encoded characters

Tags: iis

1. set request filtering on IIS to filter querying strings to deny special characters for example ">".
2. Even thought in the link when the special character ">" is encoded as "%3c", why is the link still denied by IIS and generate a 404.18.0.0 error?
3. It seems that IIS decodes url in advance, is any way to stop it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

A `>` in a URI is always encoded as `%3c`. If you had a `>` directly in a URI it wouldn't be a URI, it would be random junk. Asking for `>` to be banned and for `%3c` to be banned are asking for the same thing.

Conversely though, it's part of the whole point of having a means of escaping that if you had `%41` in a URI it should be treated exactly the same as if you had `A` there. Again, if you were banning `A` then you would also want to ban `%41` as they're the same thing. (The exception is that a character like `/` that is significant within a URI in itself should not be treated as such when escaped).

Since the point of banning `>` is to avoid XSS and other security exploits, if `>` was valid unescaped in a URI you would still want to ban `%3c` to make sure `>` didn't sneak into whatever it is that can't handle it.

Comparably, around 2000 IIS with some settings used to (incorrectly) treat `%c0%af` as `/` (incorrect in that the UTF-8 is overlong) but code that blocked `/../` from reading files outside the webroot didn't see it as `/` so the block didn't block and one could indeed read files from anywhere on the same drive as the webroot. You are asking if there's a way that you can make your system similarly vulnerable to attacks using `%3c` without being vulnerable to attacks using `>`. Even if that made any sense for URIs it's hard to see why that would be desirable.